# Including headers in header file doesn't make it included in implementation file - or am I just using wrong command to compile?

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, include

Well, I have a header (my_prog.h) which looks like this:

```
#ifndef __MY_HEADER_H
#define __MY_HEADER_H
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct {
    size_t something;
    size_t something_else;
}
void my_func();
#endif
```

and implementation file (my_prog.c) where I put:

```
#include "my_prog.h"
static size_t min(size_t a, size_t b) {...}
void my_func() {...}
```

When I try to compile my_prog.c to object file (I need it for linking with other files) I fet:

```
error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘min’
```

The command I use for compiling is:

```
gcc -c my_prog.c -o my_prog.h
```

There's no error saying that it couldn't find the source. When I include  in implementation file it compiles wihtout issues.

Comment: Post minimum compilable code that replicates the problem please.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem.  I do not get that error message.  What I get is `my_prog.h:8:1: error: expected ‘;’, identifier or ‘(’ before ‘void’`.  (Also, I'd recommend using `-Wall` and perhaps also `-Wextra` when compiling with `gcc`.)

Comment: Please vote for closing the question. As @k_wisniewski's comment below states, it was an error because of the `ifdef` used instead of `ifndef`.

Comment: You're missing a `;` after the definition of the struct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Remove the `...` from the function body. Having them is a syntax error.
2. You have not given a typedef name to the structure and the `;` is missing:

   ```
   typedef struct {
       size_t something;
       size_t something_else;
   } foo;
     ^^^^
   ```
3. In the compile line, following the `-o` you are specifying the name of your header file. This is incorrect. If the compilation goes fine(it will if you fix 1 and 2 above) , the compiler the wipe the original contents of `my_prog.h` and will overwrite it with the object file. Instead do :

   ```
   gcc -c my_prog.c -o my_prog.o
   ```

Comment: ok that was in fact stupid question. I added ... just to say that there is some body I don't want to write here (because it's not important). The real problem was that in my real code I actually had #ifdef instead of #ifndef. This topic can be closed.